# Backbone Layout Manager subview's events doesn't work after reload

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-boilerplate, backbone-layout-manager

I'm using the Backbone Layout Manager Boilerplate. Unfortunately, a quite frustrating bug occurred. I like render a list of items as subviews inserted by insertView function. At the first load everthing works fine. But after a reload the the click events doesn't work anymore :(. I already tried to call delegateEvents() on the TableItem View manually but nothing changed. I hope anyone can give me a clue.

```
App.Views.Item = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: "templates/item",
  tagName: "li",
  events: {
    "click .applyButton" : "apply",
    "click .viewDetailsButton" : "showDetail"
  },
  serialize: function() {
    return { table : this.model.toJSON() };
  },
  apply: function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert("apply button clicked");
  },
  showDetail: function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var id = this.model.get("_id");
    app.router.navigate("#events/"+ id, {trigger : true})
  }
});

/*
 * List View
 */

 App.Views.List = Backbone.View.extend({
   template: "templates/list",

   tagNam: "ul",
   className: "tableList",

   beforeRender: function() {
     var events = this.model.get("userEvents").get("hosting");


     events.each(function(model) {
       this.insertView(new App.Views.Item({ model : model }));
     }, this);
   },

   serialize: function() {
     return {};
   }
});
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. My guess is that you'll have to manually delegate events each time you call render on the top view, or any of the subviews... for me works fine, but I am not sure that's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to add a `cleanup` function on your Item view to `undelegate` the events when layoutmanager removes the view. I don't know if this will fix your problem, but it seems like good practise.

When you say *after a reload*, do you mean reloading the page with the browser reload button? if so, how do you get it to work in the first place?

It would help if you could provide a jsfiddle of your setup, or point us to a repo so we can test it on our machines. Make sure you include the router so that we can have a look at how the view and the layout that contains it are initialised.